# Python - where are Libraries stored in virtual environments?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv

I created a new VENV and pip installed awscli there.

I can see it installed with `pip list --local`.

But when I type `aws` - it does not recognize the command (even though I activated that VENV).

How to setup paths so that newly installed library in VENV can be recognized?

Comment: Did you activate the venv *before* you used `pip install`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to create a virtual environment. Let's say:

```
python3 -m venv my_venv
```

But to install some package in that particular environment, you have to activate it by:

For windows:

```
my_venv\Scripts\activate
```

For Linux or Mac:

```
source my_venv/bin/activate
```

Then if you install a package by using pip, it will be installed in that particular virtual environment. Otherwise, it will be installed in the local environment.

Comment: I used this for Mac (source first, and then Pip but still can not find it)..